# Count in python using a dictionary fuction

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I tried to count a random array for example [1,2,4,6,1,6,8,3,7,8] then output an array. I know the output isn't correct but I get this error message:
Exception : KeyError :: line 9 :: in duplicate_items counts[nums] += 1
What does this mean?

and no I don't want to use the collection module.

I know the output isn't correct yet but I want to fix the dictionary so I won't make the same mistakes. Thanks!

```
def duplicate_items(list_numbers):
    counts = {}
    new_arr = []
    for nums in list_numbers:
        if nums in counts:
            count[nums] = 1

        else:
            counts[nums] += 1
    for k in counts:
        if count[k] > 1:
            new_arr.append(k)

return sorted(new_arr)
```

Comment: You want `if nums not in counts:`

Comment: You also have typos: `count[n]` vs `counts[n]`

Comment: as an unrelated aside there is a builtin `collections.Counter` that does exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Rauch and @ Alexander

I looked at this so much I became blind. lol

Comment: You could also use `defaultdict` from the collections module, e.g. `dd = defaultdict(int): dd[nums] += 1` (although you don't want to use the collections module...).

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` and `else` in the first loop are flipped, so `counts[nums] += 1` can't find the key, this should be:

```
def duplicate_items(list_numbers):
    counts = {}
    new_arr = []
    for nums in list_numbers:
        if not nums in counts:
            counts[nums] = 1
        else:
            counts[nums] += 1
    for k in counts:
        if count[k] > 1:
            new_arr.append(k)
return sorted(new_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

@E. Sun has given the correct explanation, but you can also do it more elegantly. using `dict.get` to supply a default value if the key is not in the dict.

```
for nums in list_numbers:
    # If the key, nums is not in counts, take 0 as fallback value.
    counts[nums] = counts.get(nums, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dictionary's `get` method to return a default value when the key is missing.

```
def duplicate_items(list_numbers):
    counts = {}
    for nums in list_numbers:
        counts[nums] = counts.get(nums, 0) + 1
    new_arr = [k for (k, v) in counts.items() if v > 1]

return sorted(new_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ? You don't need to use `collections` python has a built in `.count` function you can create you `counts` dictionary using the `index` and the `count` of that index.

Then you can make your list with *list comprehension* and only add the dictionary items that have a value greater than 1

```
def dups(l_nums):
    counts = {i: l_nums.count(i) for i in l_nums}
    new_arr = [k for k in counts if counts[k] > 1]
    return(sorted(new_arr))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 time.py
> [1, 6, 8]
> ```